# How to increase the width of the image in nextGen (galleryview template) wordpress plugin?

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

I just wanted to ask you how to change the width/height of the image in nextGen (galleryview template) wordpress plugin? After I set everything up it works like charm but I can't increase the size of the image. This is the code I found inside the template:

```
<script type="text/javascript" defer="defer">
jQuery("document").ready(function(){
    jQuery('#<?php echo $gallery->anchor ?>').galleryView({
        panel_width: 650,
        panel_height: 400,
        frame_width: 40,
        frame_height: 40,
        transition_interval: 0,
        overlay_color: '#222',
        overlay_text_color: 'white',
        caption_text_color: '#222',
        background_color: 'transparent',
        border: 'none',
        nav_theme: 'dark',
        easing: 'easeInOutQuad'
    });
});
```

However the width/height here is only applying to the whole container but not to image itself. And I don't want to change these values through css either because images looks terrible then. Can anyone help me with this one pretty please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not completely sure if this is what you need, but if you want to change the default 320x240 size to something different, look in `admin/tinymce/window.php`

Comment: hmm not quite - it's true that I'm trying to change width and height of the image in the gallery but in galleryview template. That's a little bit different, but thanks anyway :)